# How to create link to specfic documnet in fireStore using dynamic links with flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, blogs, firebase-dynamic-links

I developing a blog application with firebase and flutter  and I need to share article to other user ,how can I create link for specfic article to share that and when clicked on that opens my app at article detail screen ?
articles are saved in fireStore and images are stored in storage

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your goal in many ways, but as a start point you would need some custom routing with deep linking in your application, here's some starting points that I think would help you achieve your goal:

[Navigation and routing](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/navigation)

[Deep linking](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/navigation/deep-linking)

Comment: I use named navigation in my code and I want to have this kind url to open `open://amata_blog/articles/how-to-learn-flutter`